# Font not working in ggplot even when fonts imported

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I'm trying to use a font in my ggplot boxplot to match a theme I have elsewhere. It's a standard Windows font - Franklin Gothic Book, in this instance.

I've followed the instructions in [this blog post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html), using the extrafont package and importing fonts. When I look at the font list, it includes Franklin Gothic Book. However, when I use Franklin Gothic Book in my code, it returns a warning that it wasn't found. What am I missing?

Example of where I'd get a warning:

```
boxplot +
  theme(text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 16, family = "Franklin Gothic Book")
```

I've also tried with the font name rather than the family name, which doesn't work either. The warning says "font family not found in Windows font database".